# How to call same methods inside and outside 'context' and 'it' block

Tags: ruby, rspec

Below is a simple rspec example:

```
describe 'Emails' do    
  email_ids.each do |email_id|    
    it "should display #{email_id}" do
    end    
  end    
end

def email_ids
  [
    'test1@example.com',
    'test2@example.com',
    'test3@example.com'
  ]
end
```

The above does not work, as methods are not accessible outside the `it` block.

Please advise how to make the method `email_ids` accessible outside the `it` block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using proc or scopes,
 Simply use local variables outside describe block.

```
email_ids = [ 
  'test1@example.com',
  'test2@example.com',
  'test3@example.com'
]
describe 'Emails' do
end
```

Answer (score 8):

`describe` creates a (nested) class and evaluates the given block within that class:

```
describe 'Foo' do     
  p self            #=> RSpec::ExampleGroups::Foo
  describe '' do
    p self          #=> RSpec::ExampleGroups::Foo::Bar
  end
end
```

`it` blocks on the other hand are evaluated in the corresponding class' instance:

```
describe 'Foo' do    
  it 'foo' do 
    p self          #=> #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::Foo ...>
  end
end
```

If you define a method via `def email_ids`, it becomes an *instance method* and is therefore only available within the instance, i.e. within `it`.

In order to make a method available within `describe`, you have to define it as a *class method*, i.e via `def self.email_ids`:

```
describe 'Emails' do
  def self.email_ids
    %w[test1@example.com test2@example.com test3@example.com]
  end

  email_ids.each do |email_id|
    it "should display #{email_id}" do
    end
  end
end
```

Output:

```
Emails
  should display test1@example.com
  should display test2@example.com
  should display test3@example.com
```

You can also reuse the helper method across multiple tests by putting it in a module and using `extend`. See [Define helper methods in a module](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/helper-methods/define-helper-methods-in-a-module) for more examples.

Comment: but how above 'email_ids' class method will be accessible inside 'it' block?

Comment: excellent explanation and whilst my answer provides another way to achieve what I believed the OP was attempting to do, this is the correct solution to the actual question.

Comment: @Rhunal you wanted it to be accessible _outside_ the `it` block.

Comment: Wow. Amazing explanation @Stefan.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, it works. Please advise if same method can be accessible inside/outside the it block

Comment: @Rhunal you want a method that is available as both, a class method and an instance method. Ruby has [`module_function`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Module.html#method-i-module_function) or you could put it in a module and call both, `extend` and `include` as shown in the RSpec docs (last example).

Answer (score 3):

I have better solution for this, than above.

1.using 'procs' or just local variable as below:

```
email_ids = ->{ %w[test1@example.com test2@example.com test3@example.com] }
```

`email_ids = { %w[test1@example.com test2@example.com test3@example.com] }`

Scope of `proc` & `local` variable will be same, but if you want to pass an argument then 'procs' are useful.

2.Define 'email_ids' method in `module` and include that `module` in `spec`, so that method will be accessible inside and outside the 'it' block

```
module EmailFactoryHelper

  def email_ids
    %w[test1@example.com test2@example.com test3@example.com]
  end

end
```

include in specs as below:

```
require 'factories_helper/email_factory_helper'

include EmailFactoryHelper

describe 'Emails' do
  email_ids.call.each do |email_id|
    it "should display #{email_id}" do
      page.should have_content "#{email_id}"
    end
  end
end
```

Output:

```
Emails
  should display test1@example.com
  should display test2@example.com
  should display test3@example.com

Finished in 41.56 seconds
3 examples, 0 failures
```

I have preferred step-2

Comment: You don't have to put the array in a proc, just assign it to the variable.

Comment: By assigning it to the variable, that variable will not be accessible outside the 'it' block.

Comment: If `email_ids` wouldn't be accessible, you couldn't invoke `email_ids.call`, could you?

Comment: Please specify are you talking about email_ids as proc or assigned variable?

Comment: If we define `email_ids` as proc, then we can invoke `email_ids.call`,

Comment: `email_ids` is a local variable. You can assign a proc to it or an array. That doesn't change its scope. Either one works.

Comment: If we assign a `proc` to local variable `email_ids`, then its scope is available inside or outside `it` block.
But if we assign an `array` to local variable `email_ids`, then its scope will not be work as same as `proc`.

Comment: Assigning a proc to a variable does not change its scope.

Comment: Thanks Stefen, I got it now. Its scope.remains same.

Comment: Stefen, please advise, is it right to use local variable or proc in rspec?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to simply define your structure within scope, instead of returning it from a method call:

```
EMAILS = [
   'test1@example.com',
   'test2@example.com',
   'test3@example.com'
]

EMAILS.each do |email|
  it "should display #{email}" do
  end
end
```

Comment: What if we want pass an argument like done in  'method'?, so  'procs' are useful than scope.

Comment: I agree, in that case this solution wouldn't work - it just wasn't clear from your question what your end goal was.

Answer (score 0):

The method wasn't accessible because you called the method before you defined the method.  This simpler script has the same problem:

```
p email_ids

def email_ids
  [
    'test1@example.com',
    'test2@example.com',
    'test3@example.com'
  ]
end
```

"undefined local variable or method `email_ids' for main:Object (NameError)"

You must define your methods before you call them.  You can solve this problem by moving the `def email_ids` above the `describe 'Emails'`.

Answer (score 0):

short version of @stefan's answer:
needs to be

```
def self.email_ids
 # stuff
end
```

(`def self.method` for context/describe/etc; `def method` for it/etc)